# Make hide the network adapters

Tags: networking

I Would like to hide specific network adapters in my ubuntu box which other users can't see those network adapters except their network adapters. Any idea?

Comment: Is that a server? Or a laptop/desktoip shared between people? What do you mean by "their" network adpaters? USB adapters they have to plug in?